# Git isn't working as expected with vscode remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I recently tried out [vscode's remote SSH feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). It was super easy to setup and connect to a remote server.

I opened the editor to a directory that is a git repo and expected to have the default git features working like normal. But if I edit a file, vscode isn't showing the visual indication that there is a modification in the file. And the git tab doesn't show the change. I can open the terminal in vscode and run `git status` and I do in fact see the change so I know that's actually editing the file.

If I ssh into the server and run `git status` I do notice that vscode updates and now shows the change in the git tab. But there's still no visual indication next to the line number in the actual file that is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that I was opening VSCode to a symlinked directory on the remote server. If I instead pointed it to the actual directory everything worked fine!

@depontimatteo's answer might still be relevant if someone is running into this problem with a large codebase.

Comment: It worked for me. Don't Navigate via the symbolic path, open the folder via the actual path.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me: use the -A option (forward your ssh-agent) when ssh-ing to your remote server. This will allow you to connect to git using your git credentials from the client.

Example:

```
ssh username@servername -A
```

Or just enter

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

Into your ssh-config (~/.ssh/config on ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions at this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc), I've changed the value of `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and everything was ok.